# CSS rules hierarchy and precedence

Tags: css

I have these rules:

```css
article.post p img {border: 1px solid black;}  

article.post p img.class { border: none; }
```

According to my basic CSS, the second rule should apply; it comes later and with a class, but, well, it doesn't apply. Why not?

The class is assigned by WordPress through the editor in the images options, if that matters, but I think it doesn't since the browser doesn't know that.

Comment: Can you show us a working example in your question? Use the snippet tool (the little icon with `<>` in the editor)

Comment: Can you show the html for the img tag

Comment: I think that they specified `!important`

Comment: What styles do your browser tools say are being applied here, and how? (Inline, styles.css, etc.)